# Edit subscription confirmation requests

Tags: webform-civicrm, groups

CIVICRM 4.6.27 Drupal 7

Hi,

I have subscription confirmation requests on for anyone signing up to a CIVI group via a webform.

How do i edit the text in that email. It currently says
You have a pending subscription to the "" mailing list. To confirm this subscription, reply to this email or click here.

I want to remove the reply feature as it clogs up mailboxes.

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The automated messages can be edited here:

Administer>CiviMail>Headers, Footers and Automated Messages

You can also get to this under the Mailings menu.

Hope this helps!